# Prevent the user from deleting the folder or file in sdcard

Tags: android, directory, sd-card

I am saving a folder in this location `Android/data/package-name/files/`  now I want to restrict the user to delete that folder.

How to do that?

Note: Since I am working on Expansion Files the extracted data will be saved in this location only so that when the user uninstalls the app the folder gets automatically deleted.

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible. Not only can the user delete that folder, but so can any other app on the device that has the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

Comment: ok, since i am workingon expansion files i am extracting those files and saving into this directory, if even the file is deleted from that folder then my app crashes, so what is the work around and also i have to extract the files for some reason

Comment: @Goofy: "so what is the work around" -- write a more robust app, one that does not crash. For example, catch the exception, or look to see if the file exists, and then tell the user that the data is corrupted. Whether you can recover from this, I cannot say, as I have not worked with expansion files and do not know whether you can grab data from them again later.

Comment: one possible option is check the size of the internal storage space, and in case it's a modern device (with 8gb, 16gb, etc) you write stuff on the internal storage where others don't have access. But remember to check for space, if you try that on a device with 256mb of internal storage you'll have other issues.

Comment: @Goofy, Another thing that you can not do is to prevent the user from removing the external sdcard where the folder is stored (assuming it's a removable sdcard) and replace it with another sdcard. So again, like CommonsWare suggested, you have to plan for this condition to take place and handle it, since you won't be able to prevent it.